# Why component using context, always re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, memoization

I have a question with context

below this is my code

```
 const { getValueFromKey, setValueToLocal, removeValueStorage } = useStorage<AuthStateValue>();
 const [state, setState] = useState<AuthStateValue>({ ...initialValue });

 const handleLogin = () => {
   const dataFromLocal = getValueFromKey('user-info');
   setState({ ...dataFromLocal, isAuth: true });
   setValueToLocal('access-token', state.accessToken);
 };

 const handleLogout = () => {
   setState(initialValue);
   removeValueStorage('user-info');
 };

 const userInfo = useMemo(() => ({ ...state }), [state]);
 const login = useCallback(() => handleLogin(), [handleLogin]);
 const logout = useCallback(() => handleLogout(), [handleLogout]);

 return (
   <AuthContext.Provider value={{ state: { ...userInfo }, login, logout }}>
      {children}
   </AuthContext.Provider>
 );
};`
```

in my component

```
const { login, state } = useContext(AuthContext);
```

when I using context, in spite of memoization value, but child component always re-render. Can somebody help me explain?

help me clarify context and memoization in react

Answer (score 1):

You need to memoize the entire `value` you pass to the provider so its identity doesn't change; something like this.

The functions are also memoized (with `useCallback`) so they don't change every render either.

```
function Component() {
  const { getValueFromKey, setValueToLocal, removeValueStorage } = useStorage<AuthStateValue>();
  const [state, setState] = useState<AuthStateValue>({ ...initialValue });

  const handleLogin = useCallback(() => {
    const dataFromLocal = getValueFromKey("user-info");
    setState({ ...dataFromLocal, isAuth: true });
    setValueToLocal("access-token", state.accessToken);
  }, [/* TODO */]);

  const handleLogout = useCallback(() => {
    setState(initialValue);
    removeValueStorage("user-info");
  }, [/* TODO */]);

  const value = useMemo(() => ({ state, login, logout }), [state, login, logout]);

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}
```

Comment: but my context doesn't re-render. child component is called again and again even though Context doesn't change. Maybe this solution not work for me. Thank you